# How do use the LayoutInflater inflater properly

Tags: android, listview, layout-inflater

I created the Layout design using java code only not from the XML Layout Designs. The code I used is following

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  TextView tv = new TextView(mContext);
  tv.setText(hotelList.get(position).name);
  return tv;
  }
```

How to use layoutInflator for creating layout fro this. I need 2 more textviews in a single list item. the whole list contains 10 different list items

Please provide some codes for this. Help appreciated

Comment: Hi, are you designing for ListView? give me some more details.

Comment: I am designing the layout by parsing an xml using SAX and from the parsed result , I need to show the contents in a list view by using list. Now i am showing the list using the java code, but need to show like above mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have gone through this before by having my static class too. Check this out, it will help:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = convertView;


        if ( rowView == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflator = this._activity.getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.todolistlisting, null);
            TodoListViewHolder viewHolder = new TodoListViewHolder();
            viewHolder._name        = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tVTLName);           
            viewHolder._completed   = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tVTLCCount);
            viewHolder._remaining   = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tVTLRCount);
            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);

        }

        TodoListViewHolder holder = (TodoListViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        VO_TodoList votodolist = this._items.get(position);         
        holder._name.setText(votodolist._title);            
        holder._completed.setText(votodolist._completed);
        holder._remaining.setText(votodolist._remaining);

        return rowView;     

    }
```

`TodoListViewHolder` is my view component holder here. like your `TextView`.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you know how to make XML layout for this layout. So just make the XML layout and get the object of the main layout using the following code:

```
LinearLayout mainLayout=(LinearLayout) View.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout); //if yourlayout.xml is the name of the xml file you made and put in the layout folder.
```

To get the child of the layout, let's say if it's a `TextView` with the id `text`, then the code would be:

```
TextView textView=(TextView)mainLayout.findViewById(R.id.text);
```

Comment: This is only for one textview, I need two more , total of three textview in a single list item, other 3 in the other list item.. thus there are 10 items in the list view

Comment: Then put all those 10 Views in the XML, and get their object using the same code I've used for this TextView. You need to call the first statement only one to get the object of the main Layout, which I assume would be a LinearLayout, if it's anything else, just replace LinearLayout in the code with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can add view at runtime by using inflater like this

```
LinerLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_categories_item, null);

TextView categoryValueTextView = (TextView)linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.news_category_item_value);

mMainLinearLayout.addView(categoryValueTextView);
```

Here i am inflating one text view which is there in another linear layout(this is simple linear layout which holds only textview) at runtime and adding it to my main linear layout.

you can get the inflater object in your acitivity by using getLayoutInflater(). And if you want to get inflater in adapter you have to pass inflater object to constructor of adapter from your activity.